# PHP Devel Studio Function error

Tags: php

I have 2 forms. Error and Retry.

[image]

I am typing anything in the field and press ok and I am going to the next form Retry. I am pressing ok by mouse click. It works.

But I also need a possibility to press Enter button and it will also do the same as click on "OK" button.

I used a function and timer to make it.  So first I wrote this code

```
f ($key == 13){ RetryFunc2(); };
```

in type field editor.

```
$self->visible = true;
ShowForm(Retry, SW_SHOW);
```

And of course RetryFunc2 with code

```
$self->visible = false;
c("RetryWait")->enable = true;
c('Error')->hide();
```

And if press Enter there I am getting this error.

[image]

So what I did wrong? What I need to add? As well I don't know what does`$self->visible = true;`means

Comment: "am newbie in this programm, i hope someone would help me here. " We are here to help. Avoid such sentences on your question and focus only on how better you could explain the question.

Answer (score 0):

`$self->visible = true;` change it to `$self->visible = false;`